# actionmailer strange behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, actionmailer

We have an app running delayed job which is being used to send emails. We have run into an issue where the delayed_job worker receives n number of jobs for processing. Looking at the delayed_job log it does process them all. The rails log shows it receives same number of calls and all are being processed. However we do not get all the emails.

There is no smtp error and no failures in the log whatsoever. The only thing we have been able to identify is that when the delayed_job log shows an item taking extra log time that email does not go through. But the log still shows everything is fine. below are the logs for reference.

Deleyed_Job Log:

```
2014-01-17T11:13:07+0000: [Worker(delayed_job host:ip-10-224-110-111 pid:417)] Starting job worker
2014-01-18T08:00:32+0000: [Worker(delayed_job host:ip-10-224-110-111 pid:417)] Job Class#warehouse_daily_orders_email (id=1) RUNNING
2014-01-18T08:00:35+0000: [Worker(delayed_job host:ip-10-224-110-111 pid:417)] Job Class#warehouse_daily_orders_email (id=1) COMPLETED after 2.0887
2014-01-18T08:00:35+0000: [Worker(delayed_job host:ip-10-224-110-111 pid:417)] Job Class#warehouse_daily_orders_email (id=2) RUNNING
2014-01-18T08:00:36+0000: [Worker(delayed_job host:ip-10-224-110-111 pid:417)] Job Class#warehouse_daily_orders_email (id=2) COMPLETED after 1.5629
2014-01-18T08:00:36+0000: [Worker(delayed_job host:ip-10-224-110-111 pid:417)] Job Class#warehouse_daily_orders_email (id=3) RUNNING
2014-01-18T08:00:38+0000: [Worker(delayed_job host:ip-10-224-110-111 pid:417)] Job Class#warehouse_daily_orders_email (id=3) COMPLETED after 2.0888
2014-01-18T08:00:38+0000: [Worker(delayed_job host:ip-10-224-110-111 pid:417)] Job Class#warehouse_daily_orders_email (id=4) RUNNING
2014-01-18T08:01:08+0000: [Worker(delayed_job host:ip-10-224-110-111 pid:417)] Job Class#warehouse_daily_orders_email (id=4) COMPLETED after 30.0262
2014-01-18T08:01:08+0000: [Worker(delayed_job host:ip-10-224-110-111 pid:417)] 4 jobs processed at 0.1109 j/s, 0 failed
```

Rails Production Log:

```
Rendered user_mailer/orders_email.erb (538.7ms)
Sent mail to someemail@somedomain.com (2890ms)

Rendered user_mailer/orders_email.erb (0.1ms)
Sent mail to someemail@somedomain.com (1536ms)

Rendered user_mailer/orders_email.erb (0.1ms)
Sent mail to someemail@somedomain.com (1753ms)

Rendered user_mailer/orders_email.erb (0.2ms)
Sent mail to someemail@somedomain.com (30013ms)
```

The settings for action mailer in the config:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"  

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address   => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port      => 25,
    :user_name => ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
    :password  => ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]
}
```

Comment: Anyone out there who could provide some assistance?

Answer (score 0):

add your desired gmail account  here ENV["abc@gmail.com"] and password ENV["123456"]

Comment: We already have that defined and is working just fine, why do I need to add that here?

Answer (score 0):

Raise delivery errors, so that you can find the cause:

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

Provide other parameters:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
  port:                 587,
  domain:               'example.com',
  user_name:            ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
  password:             ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"],
  authentication:       'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true  
}
```

And where you are calling the email method, add ".deliver" at the end i.e.:

```
UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver
```

For background job, You can put this snippet in exception block and can use [ExceptionNotification](http://smartinez87.github.io/exception_notification/) gem to send email with details which will help you to catch and find the reason of failure easily.

Comment: I will try these changes however, the concern I have is why do I need to add these? The issue is not that I am not able to get the mail. The issue is if we send 10 mails out, we successfully get 8 and 2 are not delivered.

Comment: There may be a problem with email accounts due to spam detection. Delivery debugging may help you to dig into this. You may also try sending email text to all email addresses from email client to verify.